# How can I display a video of mpeg encoded data in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mpeg

I have a file, which is about 32 GB large. Parts of this file are MPEG-2 encoded videoclips.
When I extract only the bytes, which represent this video and save them to a file, a video player like VLC can display them correctly. What I want/need to do is to display this video in the application I'm writing using WPF. I was hoping to wrap a stream or something like that around the data and use this as source for a media player, but the WPF MediaPlayer only takes URIs as sources. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it HAVE to be displayed directly in your application, or could you just launch a process shell by the file name and Windows automatically detects  the file type and runs media player.  Then you don't have to control anything else like pause, forward, back, etc.

Comment: It has to be in the application itself.